# AWSLambdaException: Your access has been denied by Amazon S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I"m trying to deploy my lambda function using jenkins, code commit and Amazon S3. While uploading my lambda function on post-commit hook i am getting following error,

```
    com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.AWSLambdaException: Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for bucket/Version.zip. 
S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException)
```

Does anyone know about this? please help.... Thank u....